# Rules of Engagement tags

Tags: discussion

[This new question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/27645/was-crucial-evidence-missed) is about the **Rules of Engagement 2000 film**.

[This existing question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/2154/what-happened-to-brenda) is about the unrelated **Rules of Engagement 2007-2013 sitcom**.

I tagged the first one as [rules-of-engagement](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules-of-engagement) before realising the latter already had it. They are unrelated to one another, so one of the tags will need changed. What is the usual procedure here?

Should the TV series (and original holder of the tag) be relabelled to [rules-of-engagement-tv](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules-of-engagement-tv) or should the film be relabelled [rules-of-engagement-2000](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules-of-engagement-2000)? Or is another solution preferable?

Comment: There is no clear rule for it yet. Personally I'd fare with the TV-show getting a `-tv` appendage, but that's just me. Both solutions are reasonable afterall.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson: That was my preferred option too.

Comment: The TV series is more popular according to Google (higher ranked results), IMDB (higher Moviemeter ranking), and Movies & TV (asked about first), therefore I think the TV show should keep the original tag and the movie can have a `-2000`. Whatever you decide, remember to put your criteria as an answer to [Rules for multiple media using the same name](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/questions/1427/rules-for-multiple-media-using-the-same-name).

Comment: There's no 'right' answer here - might just propose both main solutions for a popular vote.

Answer (score 4):

The TV series should be [rules-of-engagement](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules-of-engagement).  The movie should become [rules-of-engagement-2000](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules-of-engagement-2000).

Comment: +1: If Crow T Robot is correct and the TV series is more popular, which seems likely, then this seems the preferable solution.

Comment: @AndrewMartin In general popularity is not a proper criterium, though, since it is not objectively measurable at all.

Comment: I think it suffices in this case, as this is a fairly rare problem. We can make the decision now. If things change, so be it. We can tackle these on a case by case basis methinks

Comment: Its also the older of the two.  If in a couple of days this is still a tie, then I'll probably choose this one.

Answer (score 1):

The movie should be [rules-of-engagement](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules-of-engagement).  The tv series should become [rules-of-engagement-tv](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules-of-engagement-tv).